# Creating generic func to extract values from map

Tags: go

Go beginner here, I am trying to create a generic routine to extract the values from a map, I have this right now:

```
func getValues(m map[interface{}]interface{}) []interface{} {

    v := make([]interface{}, 0, len(m))

    for _, value := range m {
        v = append(v, value)
    }

    return v
}
```

and I called it like so:

```
nearby := make(map[string]Nearby)
values := getValues(nearby)
```

but I get this error:

> cannot use nearby (type map[string]Nearby) as type map[interface
>   {}]interface {} in argument to getValues

Comment: Go doesn't have generics. You could probably do something using the https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/ package though, but usually the best practice is to simply have a `getValues` function specifically for your type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [generic map value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772347/generic-map-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually best to just write the type specific code. To answer your question though, use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package:

```
func getValues(m interface{}) []interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(m)

    result := make([]interface{}, 0, v.Len())

    for _, k := range v.MapKeys() {
        result = append(result, v.MapIndex(k).Interface())
    }
    return result
}
```