# go: map of pointers or bools as map of interface

Tags: go

Suppose I have maps of different types, among them of bools and of pointers and want to pass them to some function in single way:

```golang
type Blah struct {
    name string
}

var mapBlah map[string]*Blah = make(map[string]*Blah)
var mapBool map[string]bool = make(map[string]bool)

func joinKeys(m map[string]interface{}) string {
    // returns strings.Join(keys of map)
}
```

I seemingly can't pass these maps into this function ([example](https://play.golang.org/p/A_8p_mpFs68)). How can this be done properly, or
why it can't be done if I'm missing something, please?

Comment: What you can do is `joinKeys(m interface{})`

Comment: And what shall I do inside the function then? switch of various types of maps?

Comment: Yes, here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186057/4207306) how to use reflection to handle or type switch.

Comment: Yep, I'm using reflect approach currently but was wondering if I'm missing something more straightforward. Type switch approach regretfully doesn't look great in this case :)

Comment: You can also convert `map[string]*Blah` into `map[string]interface{}`(other also)  first and then pass it but refection is a nice way to do it for you case I guess.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you already know the types, I think switching over types will be beneficial like follows.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Blah struct {
    name string
}

var mapBlah map[string]*Blah = make(map[string]*Blah)
var mapBool map[string]bool = make(map[string]bool)

func joinKeys(m interface{}) string {
    var a []string
    switch v := m.(type) {
    case map[string]*Blah:
        for k, _ := range v {
            a = append(a, k)
        }
    case map[string]bool:
        for k, _ := range v {
            a = append(a, k)
        }
    default:
    }

    return strings.Join(a, ",")

}

func main() {
    mapBlah["1B"] = &Blah{name: "first"}
    mapBlah["2B"] = &Blah{name: "second"}
    fmt.Println(joinKeys(mapBlah))

    mapBool["1Bool"] = true
    fmt.Println(joinKeys(mapBool))
}
```

For more dynamic way with some performance tradeoffs `reflection` is way to go.

Comment: Thanks! not exactly what I dreamt of, but since it clarifies current state of Go for me, this should be accepted as answer. Sorry for delay :)